# How to connect to remote mysql server from Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to connect to remote mysql server. This is how I set up my connection:-

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: 13.58.156.50
  port: 3306
  # username: <%= ENV['FOODCLUBE_DATABASE_USER_DEVELOPMENT'] %>
  # password: <%= ENV['FOODCLUBE_DATABASE_PASSWORD_DEVELOPMENT'] %>
  username: root
  password: Admin123#
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  variables:
    sql_mode: "TRADITIONAL"

development:
  <<: *default
  database: timer
  # food_delivery_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: food_club_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: food_clube_production
  username: <%= ENV['FOODCLUBE_DATABASE_USER_PRODUCTION'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['FOODCLUBE_DATABASE_PASSWORD_PRODUCTION'] %>
```

When I am trying to hit a query from the Rails console, I am getting this error message:-

```
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not an answer but is "food_clube" a typo? Maybe it should be "food_club"?

Comment: No, its not typo

Comment: I am sure you configured your remote mysql via `my.cnf` to accept connections other than localhost, right? 

Did you try reducing the `table_open_cache ` of mysql?

Comment: What is table_open_cache?